# SELECT WHERE VARCHAR brings me nothing but the value exist

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, character-encoding

I'm having troubles in the SELECT WHERE 
So i have this table fca_vehicle that has the docYear column, each row has his docYear value.

As background information, this data was inserted from a excel.CSV file, i think that encoding type might be the issue, but i couldn't find any related info...

[image]

When i try to SELECT * FROM fca_vehicles WHERE docYear = by docYear 2009 to 2020 it works fine, but only for 2007 and 2008 brings me empty response.

[image]

[image]

As you can see '2008' do exist but its not showing nothing, i also checked for blank spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned that you checked for blank spaces, but perhaps you didn't consider every possibility.  Try running the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM fca_vehicles
WHERE docYear LIKE '%2008%' OR bodyStyle LIKE '%ZJ%';
```

This would allow for any amount of leading/trailing whitespace around the values.